# How to resolve integer overflow errors in R estimation

Tags: r, estimation, computation, speedglm

I'm trying to estimate a model using *speedglm* in R. The dataset is large (~69.88 million rows and 38 columns). Multiplying the number of rows and columns results in ~2.7 billion which is outside the integer limit. I can't provide the data, but the following examples recreate the issue.

```
library(speedglm)

# large example that works 
require(biglm)
n <- 500000
k <- 500
y <- rgamma(n, 1.5, 1)
x <- round(matrix(rnorm(n*k), n, k), digits = 3)
colnames(x) <- paste("s", 1:k, sep = "")
da <- data.frame(y, x)
fo <- as.formula(paste("y~", paste(paste("s", 1:k, sep = ""), collapse = "+")))   
working.example <- speedglm(fo, data = da, family = Gamma(log))

# repeat with large enough size to break 
k <- 5000       # 10 times larger than above
x <- round(matrix(rnorm(n*k), n, k), digits = 3)
colnames(x) <- paste("s", 1:k, sep = "")
da <- data.frame(y, x)
fo <- as.formula(paste("y~", paste(paste("s", 1:k, sep = ""), collapse = "+")))   
failed.example <- speedglm(fo, data = da, family = Gamma(log))

# attempting to resolve error with chunksize
attempted.fixed.example <- speedglm(fo, data = da, family = Gamma(log), chunksize = 10^6)
```

This causes an error and integer overflow warning.

```
Error in if (!replace && is.null(prob) && n > 1e+07 && size <= n/2) .Internal(sample2(n,  :  
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning message:
In nrow(X) * ncol(X) : NAs produced by integer overflow
```

I understand the warning, but I do not understand the error. They seem to be related in this case as they appear together after each attempt.

Removing columns allows the estimation to complete. It does not seem to matter which columns are removed; removing interacted or non-interacted variables will both result in a completed estimation. The *chunksize* option was added after receiving the error initially, but has not helped.

My questions are: (1) what causes the first error? (2) is there a way to estimate models using data such that the number of rows by the number of columns is larger than the integer limit? (3) is there a better *na.action* to use in this case?

Thanks,

JP.

Running: R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)

Actual code below:

```
dft_var <- c("cltvV0", "cltvV60", "cltvV120", "VCFLBRQ", "ageV0", 
             "ageV1", "ageV8", "ageV80", "FICOV300", "FICOV650", 
             "FICOV900", "SingleHouse", "Apt", "Mobile", "Duplex", 
             "Row", "Modular", "Rural", "FirstTimeBuyer", 
             "FirstTimeBuyerMissing", "brwtotinMissing", "IncomeRatio", 
             "VintageBefore2001", "NFLD", "yoy.fcpwti:province_n") 
logit1 <- speedglm(formula = paste("DefaultFlag ~ ", 
                                   paste(dft_var, collapse = "+"), 
                                   sep = ""), 
                   family = binomial(logit), 
                   na.action = na.exclude, 
                   data = default.data,
                   chunksize = 1*10^7)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:**

Based on my investigation below, @James figured out that the problem can be avoided by providing non-`NULL` value for the parameter `sparse` in the call of the `speedglm` function, as it prevents the internal call of the `is.sparse` function.

Using the example above, the following should now work:

```
speedglm(fo, data = da, family = Gamma(log), sparse = FALSE)
```

**My original answer:**

Both the warning and the error come from the same line in the function `is.sparse` in the package `speedglm`.

The line is:

```
sample(X,round((nrow(X)*ncol(X)*camp),digits=0),replace=FALSE)
```

The warning happens because of the use of `nrow(X)*ncol(X)` for a large matrix. The `nrow` and `ncol` functions return `integer` values, which can overflow. here is an illustration.

```
nr = 1000000L
nc = 1000000L
nr*nc
# [1] NA
# Warning message:
# In nr * nc : NAs produced by integer overflow
```

The error happens because the `sample` function is confused when X is a large matrix and `size = NA`. Here is an illustration:

```
sample(matrix(1,3000,1000000), NA, replace=FALSE)
# Error in if (useHash) .Internal(sample2(n, size)) else .Internal(sample(n,  : 
# missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @Andrey. I think I understand the issue, but I'm unsure how to resolve it. Are you saying if I bypass the `sample` command in `speedglm` it should work?

Comment: I think it's time to bring this to the attention of the authors of the package. They should attempt to avoid R limitations and make it work for large data like yours.

Comment: On the other hand, the fix may be as easy as replacing `nrow(X)*ncol(X)` with `length(X)`. I do not know if you would run into any issues once this is solved.

Comment: I just emailed the package maintainer pointing him to this thread. I submitted a response below that solves the issue. Not sure if it's proper etiquette to do so, so if you'd like I can edit your response with the answer and accept it.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include your findings. I would appreciate if you accept it. I think it's worth keeping your answer as well, as it confirms your contribution to solving the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Andrey 's guidance I was able to solve the problem. The issue was the sample function in the `is.sparse` check. To bypass this I set `sparse=FALSE` in the options for `speedglm` (this should work for `sparse=TRUE` as well, though I haven't tried.) This is because `speedglm` calls `is.sparse` via `speedglm.wfit` in the following way:

```
if (is.null(sparse))
    sparse <- is.sparse(x = x, sparsellim, camp)
```

So setting `sparse` avoids the `is.sparse` function.

Using the example above, the following should now work:

```
speedglm(fo, data = da, family = Gamma(log), sparse = FALSE)
```