# MatchIt (propensity score matching package for R) throws errors concerning NAs produced

Tags: r, propensity-score-matching

I'm using the MatchIt package on a system with 128GB of RAM.

Firstly, my data does not have any NAs. My first effort, using a generalised linear model (defaults to logistic regression) and a "nearest neighbour" worked:

```
headache6MontsMatch1 <- matchit(Headache_past_six_months ~ sex + age + townsend + alcohol + smoking, method="nearest", distance="glm", data=reducedDF)
```

But, from approx 100,000 records, I lost approx 30,000 from the matching. I would like to try an optimum "full" method.

```
headache6MontsMatch2 <- matchit(Headache_past_six_months ~ sex + age + townsend + alcohol + smoking, method="full", link="probit", distance="glm", data=reducedDF)
```

Unfortunately, this throws the error:

```
NAs produced by integer overflowError in if ((nc * nr > getMaxProblemSize()) && warning.requested) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Looking further into `getMaxProblemSize()`, it appears as though I'm restricted to a hard limit for matching. So I've tried:

```
setMaxProblemSize()
```

Then double checking the problem size with `getMaxProblemSize` yields Inf.

But I'm still running into the same problem. My machine sits comfortably at around 56GB of RAM out of 128GB, the CPU is only being drained at 6% and the disk is not really being touched.

Comment: What is your `nc * nr` relative to `optmatch:::getMaxProblemSize()`?

Comment: @Chris - I'd love to know myself. Any idea how I find either?

Comment: While scratching around for the exact error, [lines 48-55](https://github.com/markmfredrickson/optmatch/blob/master/R/feasible.R) suggest a method, though still haven't found the exact error file.

Comment: Where exactly the error is being propagated may be related to the formula and not from either `matchIt` or `optmatch`, as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44398763/how-to-resolve-integer-overflow-errors-in-r-estimation), in your case perhaps `glm`. The integer overflow is saying that the class of integer (Uint8/16/32/64) is wrapping because it's run out of integers, so counting over. And setting max problem size to `inf` doesn't address this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a kind of funny error and has nothing to do with `MatchIt`. It has to do with the fact that R cannot represent large numbers as integers.

I assume you have approximately 35000 treated and 65000 control units. `optmatch` computes the problem size as `nc * nr`, where `nc` is the number of control and `nr` is the number of treated. `optmatch` stores these numbers as integers because they are the dimensions of a distance matrix used internally. With `nr = 35000` and `nc = 65000`, `nc * nr` is a very large number. R cannot represent numbers that large as integers (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14589354/struggling-with-integers-maximum-integer-size)) and produces `NA` for this value instead. Because `NA` cannot be used in an `if` statement, the error is thrown.

There is no solution to this problem except to use a smaller sample or ask the `optmatch` developers to fix this bug. They could easily fix this by converting `nc` and `nr` to double values before computing `nc * nr`.

---

Edit 8/21/21: I contacted the `optmatch` maintainers and they fixed this issue. It will be corrected in the upcoming version of `optmatch`.

Comment: Thank you Noah. Sorry, it's taken so long to reply, work has been extremely busy. Your reply has been extremely helpful.